# coin flipping competition

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution, combinatorial-game-theory

A, B, C are flipping a coin independently until they got a head (same experiment "to get a head" is repeated by these 3 people). Denote `X, Y, Z` stand for the number of flips they need, respectively. Find the probability `P(X<Y<Z)`.

My solution is that they form a permutation like `XYZ` or `XZY` etc. Each combination has same probability, so the `P(X<Y<Z)` is equal to 1/6. But if we considered 2nd solution which integrate the multibinomial distribution $P(X=x, Y=y, Z=z) = (1/2)^{(x+y+z)}$ over the domain that $1<=x<y<z<inf$, the answer is 1/21. So what's wrong with the first solution? or is there any method without the integration? Thanks!

Comment: The first solution is wrong because some of $X,Y,Z$ can be equal to each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first solution is wrong (because it ignores ties), but is also useful.  Given that there are no ties, the probability of $X<Y<Z$ is indeed $1/6$ by symmetry.  And so if the probability of there being any ties is $p$, then the correct answer should be $(1-p)/6$.

The probability of there being any ties is
$$
P[X=Y]+P[X=Z]+P[Y=Z]-2P[X=Y=Z]=\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{2}{7}=\frac{5}{7},
$$
where each term is found by summing a simple geometric series.  And so the correct answer is $(1-5/7)/6=(2/7)/6=1/21$.

Comment: +1 for wrong but useful!

Comment: Thanks! But how is P(X=Y)=1/3 and P(X=Y=Z)=1/7? the former one is deducted by 3 evenly occured occasion X=Y, Y=Z, X=Z? Then the latter one?

Comment: A tie happens when two or three players flip the same sequence…  H or TH or TTH… with probability $1/2$, $1/4$, $1/8$ for each player… and $(1/2)^2 + (1/4)^2 + (1/8)^2 + … =1/3$ (geometric series).

Answer (score 0):

The first solution does not account for ties. What if they all found a head on the first try?